# subprocess results in a different output than direct console command

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm passing a command through subprocess to copy a folder to another folder but the output comes back different

I tried using the same code of subprocess in the cmd console while the console copies the whole folder the subprocess version only copies the content of the source.

```py
subprocess.Popen('xcopy /S /Y /i C:\\sourceFolder sourceFolder', cwd='C:\\whatever\\')
```

```bsh
C:\\whatever>xcopy /S /Y /i C:\\sourceFolder sourceFolder
```

When subprocess is exectuted the folder 'whatever' is filled with 'sourceFolder' content:
`C:\whatever\(file1,file2,file3)`

When the actual command is directly executed in cmd the 'whatever' folder is filled with the 'sourceFolder' folder, which is the output I am expecting:
`C:\whatever\sourceFolder\(file1,file2,file3)`

why does this happen?

Comment: I tried xcopy with the parameters you have and it worked perfectly fine in the `subprocess`. I'm clueless.